# How to display specific image in tableview in swift 2

Tags: ios, uitableview, switch-statement, swift2

I want to display specific image in tableview depending on json data taken. My images are in assets on local folder.

Let say json is:

```
[
{
"name": "john",
"car": "bmw",
},
{
"name": "mike",
"car": "audi",
}
{
"name": "ana",
"car": null,
}
{
"name": "nick",
"car": "mazda",
}
]
```

My images in assets:

```
bmw.jpg 
audi.jpg 
nothing.jpg // to display "ana" image
```

**I dont have** image mazda.jpg.

Property:

```
var name: [String] = []
var image: [String] = []
```

So I parse json data into array of strings... and I am having problem in table cells

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

let imageName = image[indexPath.row]
cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
```

My goal is if "name" is "john" display local image "bmw" in tableview

EDITED:

I managed to display image, but what will I do with null and "mazda"

I try switch statement like:

```
switch imageName {
        case  "" :
        cell.imageLabel.image = UIImage(named: "nothing")
        case imageName:
        cell.imageLabel.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        case: // need code for all others that I dont have image
        cell.imageLabel.image = UIImage(named: "nothing")
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let imageName = image[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Edited text tnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

This code will try to create an image with the name from your image array, and if it fails to create one (the ana and nick cases) it will use "nothing" instead.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    if let imageForRow = UIImage(named: image[indexPath.row]) where indexPath.row >= image.count {
        cell.imageView.image = imageForRow
    } else {
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "nothing.jpg")
    }

    return cell
}
```